# C++ overloading operator of pointer to object

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I have written a class to contain a map, the class actually has a lot more methods but the relevant parts are basically this:

```
class myContainer{
    std::map<int, std::string> names;
        
    std::string operator[](int num){
        return names[num];
    }
}
```

Simple `[]` operator overloading, and it works properly.
Then, I usually work with pointers to `myContainer` like `myContainer* cont = new myContainer;`, so I have to do something like `(*cont)[num]` to use the overloaded operator. Is there a way to make it cleaner? Ideally just `cont[num]`... but it's problematic because I know you can't overload operators on pointers. So is there a cleaner way of doing this? The best idea I had was just define a new method

```
std::string getName(int num){
    return names[num];
}
```

Then I could do `cont->getName(num)`, but that's even less comfortable than my other option. Is there a way to anyway overload `[]` on the pointer in this case?

Comment: `getName(cont, num);`?

Comment: But why using pointer?

Comment: @Jarod42 using an "external" function like `getName` is a good idea, I guess it will work.
I am using pointers because `myContainer` is allocated separately, and the scope I am in knows about the pointer. In the question I tried to simplify my situation.

Comment: "because `myContainer` is allocated separately" is insufficient to justify using a pointer.   Pointers are badly misused in C++, particularly by developers who are used to other languages that require initialising objects using `new`.

Comment: Containers shouldn't need to be allocated dynamically.  Generally it i considered a design flaw to `new` up a container.

Comment: @NathanOliver interesting, why is that bad? specifically the class I use is changed by multiple sources so I figured I should create is in one central place and let the rest of the code interact with it through a pointer, that way changes can be recognized by everyone. maybe I just don't understand what's the meaning of "container" and the naming causes confusion?

Comment: It is the purpose of containers to manage dynamically allocated objects. Managing dynamically allocated containers is like me hiring a tow-truck in order to tow my own car to work every day, with myself sitting in the driver seat and doing nothing.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that makes sense! thank you for the explanation